# Is there an efficient method to check for 8 successive elements that are not NA (i.e. is.na()==FALSE) in each column of a large dataset?

Tags: r

I have 200 datasets with size of 5120*732 and I saved them in a List-type variable "data".
Some of the elements are NA.

For example,the 13th and 14th columns are:

```
... 13 14 ...

... 13 14 ...

... NA 14 ...

... NA 14 ...

... 13 14 ...

... 13 14 ...

... 13 14 ...

... 13 14 ...

... 13 14 ...

... 13 14 ...
```

Now in each column after the 12th column(i.e. from the 13th column), once there're >= N1 (N1 = 8) successive elements that are not NA (i.e. is.na()==FALSE), I would like to prefix all of them with 'D'.

Like:

```
... 13 D14 ...

... 13 D14 ...

... NA D14 ...

... NA D14 ...

... 13 D14 ...

... 13 D14 ...

... 13 D14 ...

... 13 D14 ...

... 13 D14 ...

... 13 D14 ...
```

Here's my code:

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) { #traverse List"data"
 for (j in 1:dim(data[[i]])[1]) { #traverse each row
   for (k in 13:dim(data[[i]])[2]) { #traverse each column
      #Here N1 = 8
     if((j+N1-1)<=dim(data[[i]])[1] && sum(is.na(data[[i]][j:(j+N1-1),k])==FALSE)==N1) {
       data[[i]][j:(j+N1-1),k] <- paste('D', data[[i]][j:(j+N1-1),k], sep = '')
     }
   } 
 }
}
```

It works on small datasets but it's way too slow for large datasets.

Is there an efficient method to check for 8 successive elements that are not NA (i.e. is.na()==FALSE) in each column of a large dataset?

Thank you in advance!

I tried the apply() function but I don't know how to complete it.

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {  
  apply(data[[i]][,13:732], MARGIN = c(1,2),function(x){

  })
}
```

@RonakShah, here's an example(N1 = 3, 10 rows * 10 columns), please let me know if you need more information.

Original data:    ====================== >   Expected Outcome:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10      1  2  D3  D4  5  6   D7  D8  D9  D10  

NA 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10      NA 2  D3  D4  5  6   D7  D8  D9  D10  

1  NA 3  4  NA NA 7  8  9  10      D1 NA D3  D4  NA NA  D7  D8  D9  D10  

1  NA 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10      D1 NA D3  D4  5  6   D7  D8  D9  D10  

1  NA 3  4  NA NA 7  8  NA NA ===> D1 NA D3  D4  NA NA  D7  D8  NA  NA

NA NA 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  NA      NA NA D3  D4  5  D6  D7  D8  D9  NA

NA NA 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  NA      NA NA D3  D4  5  D6  D7  D8  D9  NA

1  NA 3  4  NA 6  7  8  9  NA      1  NA D3  D4  NA D6  D7  D8  D9  NA

1  NA 3  4  NA 6  7  8  9  NA      1  NA D3  D4  NA D6  D7  D8  D9  NA

NA NA 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  NA      NA NA D3  D4  5  D6  D7  D8  D9  NA
```

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example where `N1 = 3` (or similar) and data is 10 rows X 10 columns and show expected output based on that?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *once there're >= 8 successive elements*? Every 8th column after the 12th? Apparently `NA`'s are considered too, aren't they?

Comment: @RonakShah Hi RonakShah, I added an example in the post. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic  Hello RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic, thank you for your comment!  `NA`'s are not considered. What I mean is check each column after the 12th. For example, we first check the 13th column, in this column, once there're 8 or more successive elements/rows (not `NA`), I will prefix these successive elements. I edited the post and added an example at the end of the post with N1 = 3, I guess it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what the question asks for.
The function that does all the work is `append_one`. It

1. Creates a vector `Y` repeating the prefix `length(x)` times.
2. Gets the runs of vector `y`.
3. Cleans the runs' values to the empty string `""` if the runs' lengths are less than `N`.
4. Reverses the run-length encoding.
5. Pastes this vector of prefixes with the input vector `x`.

Then function `append_all` calls this function on every column of the input data frame.

```
append_one <- function(x, N, pref = "D"){
  y <- rep(pref, length(x))
  is.na(y) <- is.na(x)
  r <- rle(y)
  r$values[r$lengths < N] <- ""
  y <- inverse.rle(r)
  paste0(y, x)
}

append_all <- function(X, n, pref = "D"){
  Y <- X
  Y [] <- lapply(Y, append_one, N = n, pref = pref)
  Y
}

N1 <- 3
append_all(df1, N1)
```

**Data.**

Original data set, posted in the question.

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,NA,1,1,1),
                  c(2,2,NA,NA,NA),
                  c(3,3,3,3,NA),
                  c(4,4,4,4,4),
                  c(5,NA,5,NA,5))
```

New data set and corresponding output, posted in a comment.

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1.0,NA,1.1,1.2,1.3),
                  c(2.0,2.1,NA,NA,NA),
                  c(3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3,NA),
                  c(4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4),
                  c(5.0,NA,5.1,NA,5.2))

df2 <- data.frame(c(1.0,NA,'D1.1','D1.2','D1.3'),
                  c(2.0,2.1,NA,NA,NA),
                  c('D3.0','D3.1','D3.2','D3.3',NA),
                  c('D4.0','D4.1','D4.2','D4.3','D4.4'),
                  c(5.0,NA,5.1,NA,5.2))
```

Comment: Thank you Rui Barradas - Reinstate Monic! I ran your code but it only prints out the expected outcome. I hope the code can make change on the original dataset. I tried "  ```X <- Y``` in the append_all function but it doesn't work.  You may run the code with this : ```df1 <- data.frame(c(1,NA,1,1,1),c(2,2,NA,NA,NA),c(3,3,3,3,NA),c(4,4,4,4,4),c(5,NA,5,NA,5))
```

Comment: @JoyceZ `df1 <- append_all(df1, N1)` works with me. The function as posted in my answer returns a data frame with the values changed, you must assign that return value back to the original df. Or, if you want to keep the original, to `df2 <- append_all(etc)`.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. However, what if the case is: ```df1 <- data.frame(c(1.0,NA,1.1,1.2,1.3),c(2.0,2.1,NA,NA,NA),c(3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3,NA),c(4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4),c(5.0,NA,5.1,NA,5.2))``` and the expected outcome is : ```df2 <- data.frame(c(1.0,NA,'D1.1','D1.2','D1.3'),c(2.0,2.1,NA,NA,NA),c('D3.0','D3.1','D3.2','D3.3',NA),c('D4.0','D4.1','D4.2','D4.3','D4.4'),c(5.0,NA,5.1,NA,5.2))
```  I tried ```r <- rle(is.na(x)==FALSE)``` in the ```append_one``` function but it seems wrong.

Comment: @JoyceZ Done, see the edit. The function has changed.