# Want to detect >=8 consecutive elements that are not NA (i.e. is.na()==FALSE) in each row of a large dataset

Tags: r

I have 200 datasets with size of 5120*732 .Some of the elements are NA.

Now in each row, once they're >= N1 (N1 = 8) consecutive elements that are not NA (i.e. is.na()==FALSE), I would like to prefix all of them with 'D'.

Here's a example with N1 = 3.

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1.0,NA,1.1,1.2,1.3),
                  c(2.0,2.1,NA,NA,NA),
                  c(3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3,NA),
                  c(4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4),
                  c(5.0,NA,5.1,NA,5.2))
```

The expected outcome should be:

```
df1_expected <- data.frame(c('D1.0',NA,1.1,1.2,1.3),
                           c('D2.0','D2.1',NA,NA,NA),
                           c('D3.0','D3.1','D3.2',3.3,NA),
                           c('D4.0','D4.1','D4.2',4.3,4.4),
                           c('D5.0',NA,'D5.1',NA,5.2))
```

Here's the code I modified from this post but it doesn't work as expected.

[Is there an efficient method to check for 8 successive elements that are not NA (i.e. is.na()==FALSE) in each column of a large dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59917833/is-there-an-efficient-method-to-check-for-8-successive-elements-that-are-not-na?noredirect=1#comment105959910_59917833)

Any hints or tips greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
append_one <- function(x, N, pref = "D"){
  y <- rep(pref, length(x))
  is.na(y) <- is.na(x)
  r <- rle(y)
  r$values[r$lengths < N] <- ""
  y <- inverse.rle(r)
  paste0(y, x)
}

append_all <- function(X, n, pref = "D"){
  Y <- X
  Y [] <- apply(Y, 1, append_one, N = n, pref = pref)  #where I modified
  Y
}
```

Comment: Essentially you want to look at the first three rows (above) and put a `D` in front of values that are not `NA`?

Comment: Also why is `D1.0` column not have `D1.1` vs column `D5.0` has `D5.1`?

Comment: @akash87 Hello akash87, I would like to check each row. For example, in the first row (in example "df1"), there're 5 consecutive elements that are not ```NA```, so I prefix them with ```D```. In the second row, ```2.1 3.1 4.1``` are consecutive, there're 3 (which is >=N1) consecutive elements, so I prefix them. In the third row, ```3.2 4.2 5.1``` are consecutive. In the 4th row, ```3.3 4.3``` are consecutive but 2<N1, so I don't prefix them. In the 5th row, ```4.4 5.2``` are consecutive but 2<N1, so I don't prefix them neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one base R solution that you can try

```
N1 <- 3
df1_expected <- data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, function(v) {
  r <- rle(!is.na(v))
  idx <- rep(r$lengths >=N1 & r$values,r$lengths)
  replace(v,which(idx),paste0("D",v[idx]))
})))
```

such that

```
> df1_expected
    v1   v2   v3   v4   v5
1   D1   D2   D3   D4   D5
2 <NA> D2.1 D3.1 D4.1 <NA>
3  1.1 <NA> D3.2 D4.2 D5.1
4  1.2 <NA>  3.3  4.3 <NA>
5  1.3 <NA> <NA>  4.4  5.2
```